# What's up with the inconsistent drop shadow when exported from CorelDRAW X5?

Tags: corel-draw

I am expecting to export images from my CorelDRAW project and see them exactly as they appear in CorelDRAW. However this is not what I am getting...
Dropped Shadows appear a lot more prominent when exported; jpeg for web, prepress pdf, etc. Any export yields the same anomaly. 
In fact, even when the image is rendered for export in the Export Dialog, the shadow already looks more pronounced then it should be.
Actually, I noticed some drop shadow appearance color changing over complex backgrounds; black becomes grey, etc.
Is there a setting I am missing?  Any ideas? 
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the software to me.

Comment: Do other effects export as expected?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you're using **CMYK** when creating new document, but export as **RGB**. **The output color will be different**. First I encountered this problem back in 2005, but after consulting my friend then I know how to fix this problem.

Actually CorelDRAW is designed for large printing company & advertising company that heavily depend on CMYK Printer. That's why most of product you find on supermarkets designed with CorelDRAW (remember that Barcode feature on CorelDRAW).

Comment: Hi Tidy Star, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: This could be the main reason. Also one need to check if the profiles are embeded or not. In general this exports are pretty consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I've found something at Corel forums: http://coreldraw.com/forums/t/28613.aspx. Corel is not my ride but I really hope this helps until more convenient solution is found.

To summarise that link, it sounds like a bug in CorelDRAW X5 where the only known workarounds are using a screenshot of the screen instead of exporting the layered image, or, breaking up the drop shadow before exporting.

Their demonstration of the same problem (the shadow effects being reset on export):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

export image as a **PSD** fomrat and then save **PNG** file via **Photoshop** this problem will be solved..

Comment: Exporting to PSD or AI from CorelDRAW fails pretty much every time.  I am migrating to AI and Photoshop ad ditching CarelDRAW and Paint Shop. I will only keep this software for back compatibility.